# Search cell for multiple strings and return multiple values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm creating a spreadsheet which will insert a value in certain cells based on the contents of other cells but have hit a brick wall with the problem below.

Cell A1 will contain one of 16 possible strings.
Based on which string is in this cell I want to return a number in the range 1-6 in B1.
e.g. "bedroom", "ensuite" and "lounge" will return 2,
     "door" will return 4,
     "fire" will return 6.

I also want to apply this to each cell in each column.

Is this possible?

Comment: Google `instr`, `case`, loops... Edit: a `vlookup` should work too (unclear if searched string is whole or not).

Comment: It's possible... That's the answer to your question. If you want to get more details then you must provide more details as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the following formula on cell `B1`:

```
=SUM(IF(A1={"bedroom","ensuite","lounge","door","fire"},{2,2,2,4,6},""))
```

You can extend this by adding more descriptors with corresponding output values. Note that this does not need to be inputted as an array formula. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That formula works perfectly for the examples i gave. However I should have realised that each bedroom/ensuite etc will have a specific number e.g. bedroom 1, bedroom 2..... I have tried using the * wildcard but can't get it to work.

Comment: And is that consistent? ie "roomtype #". If it is  you can change so it compares only with the first word before a space using `=SUM(IF(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)={"bedroom","ensuite","lounge","door","fire"},{2,2,2,4,6},""))` Cheers